# Book: boy with telekinesis, joins an organization, learns to control his powers while watching a football game

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy, powers, telekinesis

I've been searching for a while and I can't seem to find anything online about it.

The boy gets telekinetic powers and joins some sort of small organisation with a girl in it who helps him. He goes to school and there's a (new?) boy with telepathy who doesn't want him to know he has powers, but the main character speaks to him with telepathy too (I dont quite remember how).

I vividly remember that the main character goes to a football game with one of the guys who is helping him and he learns to control his powers by helping one of the teams win the game by steadily steering the ball towards the goal.

He also learns to juggle loads of things at a time to impress a girl who he knows quite well and he messes up when actually showing her and ends up exposing that he has powers?

Comment: "...he learns to control his powers by helping one of the teams win the game by steadily steering the ball..." that would be telekinesis? What other powers did characters have other than telepathy?

Comment: Remembering some fragments if it's the same book. He gets his power through biofeedback and controlling his theta waves.

Comment: When did you first read the book, approximately? (For instance, if the answer were "at least 20 years ago," that would tell me to concentrate on things written in the 20th Century instead of more recently.)

Comment: A little late, ala, but [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/268335/45698) seems to match.