# Sci fiction / fantasy novel about a teenager with telekinesis but couldn't control it not until a mysterious young man taught him

Tags: story-identification, science

The novel is more of a teen sci-fi book. I can't remember the author, but it's somewhere along the line of Anthony Horowitz.

It's a paper back series novel. I read it in my high school's library sometime in 2014/2015. It seems like there are other teenagers with similar powers in the series. The telekinetic teenager is the first book in the series.

A teenager discovers he has telekinesis but doesn't know how to control it. A particular scene keeps playing on my mind. A young man approached this teenager, took him to his house, more like a basement with junk, old car tires and stuff, and the young man helped the teenager learn how to control his power. In particular, he asked him to move the tires with his thoughts and after several failed attempt, the teenager managed to lift the tires off the basement floor for a few minutes.

Another scene was when the young man took the telekinetic teenager to a football game, and placed a bet on a particular team. Towards the last minute of the match, the young man turned to the teenager and told him to use his telekinetic powers on the ball to score some goals so as to win the match for the team he had already placed a bet on, which the teenager reluctantly did. The team won the match, thanks to the teenager and the young man shared the winnings from his bet with the telekinetic teenager.

Comment: Please visit [this set of prompts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can [edit] more details into your question. Like, when did you read this? Was this in a school library? Paperback? Hardback? Online? Were there other people with powers in the book?

Comment: Maybe related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207372/book-boy-with-telekinesis-joins-an-organization-learns-to-control-his-powers, which unfortunately has no answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

*The Medusa project*
By Sophie McKenzie

First book is called *[The Set Up](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6562560-the-set-up)*.

> Thirteen years ago, Professor William Fox discovered DR6124 - a gene for psychic abilities. By synthesising it, he managed to implant it in a series of embryos, knowing that the gene would be kick-started at puberty. But Fox was killed by his business partner, Jack Linden, before he saw his experiment come to fruition. Jack has big plans for the kids with the psychic gene - IF he can track them down… though Fox's brother, Fergus, is determined to stop him and keep the kids safe: Nico - telekinetic and cocky with it; Ketty - clairvoyant and terrified she's seen her brother's murder; Dylan - a mind-reader with morals; and Alicia - able to withstand physical pain through the power of her mind. Can Fergus keep them - and his brother's experiment - a secret?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should explain something about this story to demonstrate how it matches the question.  You might want to read [answer].